Equivalence of Abel's inequality in integral form and sequence form

Abel Inequality (Sequence form) The sequence $a_n$ is monotonic then$$\left|\sum_{k=1}^n a_k b_k\right| \leq \max _{k=1, \ldots, n}\left|\sum_{i=1}^k b_i\right|\left(\left|a_n\right|+|a_n-a_1|\right)$$


Abel Inequality (Integral form) The Riemann integrable function $f(x)$ is monotonic then$$\left|\int_a^b f(x)g(x)dx\right| \leq \sup _{\xi\in[a,b]}\left|\int_a^\xi g(x)dx\right|\left(\left|f(b)\right|+|f(b)-f(a)|\right)$$

These two inequality should be equivalent. We can take $f$ and $g$ as some special step functions then derive the sequence form from the integral form.
But how can we derive the integral form from the sequence form? A possible way is proving the second mean value theorem for definite integrals firstly. But I think they're equivalent. So how can I prove the integral form by using sequence form with out second mean value theorem for definite integrals?

What are the assumptions  on $f$ and $g$? Continuous? Riemann or Lebesgue integrable?

There is an error in your integral with $\xi$ cause you integrate on the variable which is in the integral bound.  And for the exercise what about a Riemann sum from discrete case ?

@EDX Thanks, there was a typo. Now it has been corrected.

@MartinR, they're just Riemann integrable, like the case in the second mean value theorem for definite integrals. And f(x) is monotonic.

@EDX, Do you mean that I treat discrete form inequalities as Riemann sums? Could you show the details please?

Yes, you can write for example $a_k=f(a+k\dfrac{b-a}{n}) $ and $b_k=g(a+k\dfrac{b-a}{n})$, using monotonic properties because $f$ is monotonic.

@EDX, OK, Thanks!

Answer
For $g$ and $f$ Riemann integrable.
$$\left|\sum_{k=1}^n a_k b_k\right| \leq \max _{k=1, \ldots, n}\left|\sum_{i=1}^k b_i\right|\left(\left|a_n\right|+|a_n-a_1|\right)$$
Noting for $k \in [1,n]$ :
$$ a_k=f(a+(k-1)\dfrac{b-a}{n-1})$$
$$a_1=f(a)$$
$$a_n=f(a+(n-1)\dfrac{b-a}{n-1}) = f(b)$$
$$ b_k=g(a+(k-1)\dfrac{b-a}{n-1})$$
Both increasing because $f$ and $g$ do so :
$$\left|\dfrac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^n a_k b_k\right| \leq \max _{k=1, \ldots, n}\left|\dfrac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^k b_i\right|\left(\left|a_n\right|+|a_n-a_1|\right)$$
By terms
LHS tends to $$ \int_{a}^bf(x)g(x)dx $$
And
$$ a_n = f(b) $$
$$a_1=f(a)$$
For the max :
$$ \lim_{n \to \infty} \max_{k=1,...,n} \left|\dfrac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^kb_i\right|\leq\sup_{\xi\in[a,b]} \left|\int_{a}^{\xi}g(x)dx\right|$$
(In order to be sure of it look at the expression of $a_n$ and $b_n$, you can also proove it by developing and taking the expression and definition of the max and the sup, and limits)
Which ends the problem and gives the results.

There is a problem that $f$ may not be continuous. I said that $f$ is just Riemann integrable.

I modify it so you dont need it.

For the last equation, it's what I was confused about from beginning to end. I've tried for a long time and couldn't prove it.

It is really possible to prove them just by definition alone?

Yes look what can become the $ \lim \max$ when $n$ tends to $\infty$ and see how the inner parameter in $b_k=f(..)$ evolves and describes $\mathbb{R}$ or $\mathbb{Q}$

Can you show the details? I still cannot complete it with definition.
